# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine in 64 Bit Machine

Tags: c#, windows

I am working in Windows Application. I am reading a value from Excel and updating into the database.
My code is

```
 string Con_Str = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath +
                         ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
```

Its working fine in my local and i am having 32 Bit Machine. I ran the exe in Server which is 64 Bit Machine. There i am getting the error like

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I had downloaded the latest from this link..

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Still i am getting the Issue. How to fix this..

Comment: You might need the latest [Jet 4.0 SP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114)

Comment: You need to installed ADE. Try this.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: In your link above, you should see two different downloads. One for 32bit and one for 64bit.

Comment: @shai Which version of JEt 4.0 SP Should i install...

Comment: @sarooptrivedi: i had tried with those but no use..Still i am getting the same error

Comment: @Shai JET4.0 doesn't exists for 64bit-

Comment: @RobinHood: I face same problem with Access 2007. Not remember sure but you need to create the Datasource for the Access.This is very common problem. You getting solution on Microsoft site easily.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` (ADE for short). This means that you need to install the appropriate bits on your target machine. This is complicated by the Architecture choosen when you build your application.

**You build for AnyCPU:**

```
Install ADE 32bit on 32bit target machine
Install ADE 64bit on 64bit target machine
```

**You build for x86**

```
Install ADE 32bit on 32bit or 64bit target machine.
```

As you can see, the easiest way to get out is to compile your application for x86 architecture.

Comment: my machine is 32 bit..should i install ADE 32 bit in my machine and build the application and i should install ADE 64Bit in server...Like this i should do...Platform Target : ANYCPU..

Comment: Whether this is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8125 Jet 4.0 latest..?

Comment: As I have said. You build for AnyCPU, so in your dev machine (32bit OS) with ADE 32bit installed everything works fine. When you install your (AnyCPU) app on a 64bit machine it requires the 64bit version of ADE and it can't find it. So install the 64bit ADE on your server.

Comment: You are using ADE not JET, so the JET4.0 is not required. And it cannot be used on 64bit machine by an application compiled for AnyCPU because JET is only 32bit.

Comment: Still i am getting the same error : The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: I had downloaded _X64.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and installed. ANYCPU as Platform Target..

Comment: This [article](http://www.arboundy.com/2010/11/the-microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/) explain the process

Comment: Then you should build your app for 32 bits, and install the 32bit version on the server. I don't think you can have both the 32 and the 64 bit variants on a system.

Comment: I had build the application in 32Bit. Moved the application to the server and ran the exe. The server is 64 Bit..I had installed ADE 64 bit in server..But same error is coming..\

Comment: In my server i am not having Microsoft office..Whether that might be the issue..?

Comment: 32bit app use 32bit drivers, you can't have ADE32 and ADE64 installed on the same machine. Deinstall ADE64 and install ADE32, or build for AnyCPU. Your choice.