# OleDb conflicts with Windows 7 running MS Office 2007

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

The program runs perfectly in Windows XP running MS Office 2007 but not in Windows 7 running MS Office 2007. So I decided to use Microsoft.Ace, so I used this connectionString:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    + "Data Source=\"" + strDir + "\\\";"
    + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
```

This is the method:

```
public DataTable Load(string path, int columnCount)
{
    CreateSchema(path, columnCount);
    DataTable dtData = new DataTable();

    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    string csvFile = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);

    string query;

    string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
      + "Data Source=\"" + directoryName + "\\\";"
      + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

    query = "SELECT * FROM " + csvFile;

    OleDbDataAdapter dtAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);

    dtAdapter.Fill(dtData);

    dtAdapter.Dispose();

    return dtData;
}
```

My main problem is, the program runs in Windows XP running MS Office 2007 but not in Windows 7 running MS Office 2007 when I use this connectionString:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    + "Data Source=\"" + strDir + "\\\";"
    + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
```

I came up with my research that I need to use ACE so I used this connectionString:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    + "Data Source=\"" + strDir + "\\\";"
    + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
```

But still doesnt help. Please help me! THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two connection strings are for different kind of files.
The first one is for text files, the second one is for Excel 2007

The first one use as DataSource a directory name,
the second one requires the name of an Excel file as input on `strDir`

See [connectionstrings for Excel2007](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007)
and [connectionstrings for Text Files](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile)

This is probably the source of the error you have now on ACE.
Regarding the error on XP I can only suppose that is related to a missing JET/ACE driver. In that case, the problem is due to the Platform for which you have compiled your application. Please look at [this question and related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078675/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-i)

Comment: I see your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078675/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-i, can this be my problem also?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but without knowing you exact error message it is not possible to be sure. Please post the error message received

Comment: This is the exception get: microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local

Comment: Yes then, this is the exact symptom. An application compiled for AnyCPU that tries to load a 32 bit driver on a 64bit OS or some other mismatch between your code, operating system and driver

Comment: thanks then, I will build to x86 and try it to my client's PC

Comment: the solution you provided in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078675/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-i helped me. thanks a lot Steve!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Added the link to that helpful answer