# Making a Standalone of my Project which has a MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, installation

Finally I made my own system in visual basic 2013, which has a database (MS Access).

Already published it and when I installed it to a computer of my friend it has an error when I try to login. The login form will access the ms database to it can continue and the other information in that ms access database will be access also for later use.

So when I click the login button I got this error: `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

How can I fix this and include on my exe file. Or any thoughts about this one?

Comment: Several things to think about: connections string and database location, is Access installed on target machine?

Comment: @OneFineDay Yes... All ms office program were installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461072/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-thoug) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?rq=1)

Is your app installed on a 64-bit computer? If so then click the links, it has an accepted answer there.