# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not registered on the Local Machine?

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit, ms-access-2007

I am getting this error when i am trying to install VS project in a 64 bit System. I already download and install **AccessDatabaseEngine** . There is any other method to do that, i am using MS Access(**Office 2007**) database to my application. both systems are using **x32 system tools **. if i am installing **AccessDatabaseEngine(x64)** it is getting an error your system consists of (**x32 system tools**)

Comment: please take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f11b2df9-fd0a-4528-987f-f95dfdccee0a/microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-error?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: There are tons of question about this. Just look at the related column on the right

Comment: possible duplicate of [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine in 64 Bit Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078675/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-i)

Comment: hi the client Office is expired...,

Answer (score 6):

Try to find out your solution from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

`For Web`

If you have installed the `AccessDataEngine` and are still getting the Not Registered error

AND

you are running IIS7 on a 64 bit server,

MAKE SURE

you have enabled 32-bit applications for the application pool associated with the website.  In `IIS`,  Right click on the application pool.  In the properties window, the 2nd option from the top is "Enable 32-Bit Applications".  Set it to true.

Comment: it is a windows application

Comment: @Anjali Please check my link it will help you.

Comment: i already check those links. based on that only i installed accessdataengine

Comment: in client system it is (Office2010)

Comment: Please check http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/

Comment: Please Join for more discussion chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38952/room-for-amit-agrawal-and-anjali